# bootstrap-tags-input adding a class to the generated input

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I would like to add a class or other attributes to the input generated by bootstrap

```
<input type="text" value="">
$('input').tags-input();
```

generates:

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
  <input type="text" placeholder="add tags" style="width: 8em !important;">
</div>
```

I would like to add a class with:
https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

> **input**
>
> Returns the tagsinput's internal , which is used for adding tags. You 
>   could use this to add your own typeahead behaviour for example.
>
> `var $elt = $('input').tagsinput('input');`

I don't seem to understand how would a class be added

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, tagsinput is initialized like this

```
$("input").tagsinput();
```

The method `tagsinput('input')` returns the input element to which other jQuery methods can be used like this

```
var $input = $("input").tagsinput('input');
$input.addClass('custom-class');
```

Comment: I am getting input object not html element. Given quirkiness of this lib in complex environments, it is more reliable to use wrapper and code like this: $('.bootstrap-tagsinput input').addClass('classname');