# how to add a class to the input element generated by bootstrap-tagsinput

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I tried the solution suggested in [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231752/bootstrap-tags-input-adding-a-class-to-the-generated-input):

```
$("input[name='tags']").tagsinput('input').addClass('form-control');
```

But I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagsinput(...).addClass is not a function

I also tied:

```
$("input[name='tags']").tagsinput({
    tagClass: 'form-control'
});
```

But it still couldn't add a `form-control`

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add `data-role="tagsinput` and `.tagsinput('item')`

Comment: can you please show your html?

Comment: @magreenberg after adding data-role="tagsinput", the first method is working now. Thank you very much. By the way, any idea why the second one doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I also had same problem here [Bootstrap Tags Input, assign class to tags based on ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025608/bootstrap-tags-input-assign-class-to-tags-based-on-ajax-call).

I tried a hacky way. In DOM tag is stored in  with class 'tag'.
So I used simple jQuery Selectors to achieve this:

```
 $("span.tag:contains("+event.item+")").addClass('label-success');
```